# Session lost in Laravel / React app on BigCommerce

Tags: reactjs, laravel, session, bigcommerce

I'm currently working on BigCommerce application using Reactjs and Laravel. To install app in BigCommerce, there are three important routes (install, load and uninstall). I placed them in the web.php file. The view route is also in the web.php file. All others routes are placed in api.php file.

At the start, I get the logged in client in PHP and I store the data in the session. But after redirect, the session is lost and a new one is created for each request (redirection and api calls).

The only way I keep the same session is when I return a view instead of redirect url. However, I can't return view because I'm using React and not blade views as front.

Has anyone ever had this problem before and find a way to persist session ?

Comment: Hi Laure, I was going to ask about your routes, but see that you mentioned these are set up. I'd like to share this article with you as it dives deeper into testing authentication of apps. It's not 1:1 to your question, but it may be helpful to look at the routes you have set up in your php file. 
https://medium.com/bigcommerce-developer-blog/how-to-test-app-authentication-locally-with-ngrok-149150bfe4cf

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is an interesting article. Finally last evening, a colleague found a solution by using Laravel Sanctum to login user without form. That allows the persistence of the session and protects routes access. Moreover, you mentioned the routes. It was apparently a part of the problem : they had to be placed in web.php file.

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks for coming back to let us know! I'm glad to hear this was solved by adjusting your routes and utilizing Laravel Sanctum. :)

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments -- This was solved by having all routes in the web.php file and utilizing Laravel Sanctum to allow the persistence of the session and protect to the routes access. :)